# Where in the books of Ahl al-Kitab the Sahaba were mentioned?

Tags: tafseer, reference-request, sahaba, bible, torah

Allah the Almighty gives us two examples in surat al-Fath ([48:29](http://legacy.quran.com/48/29)):

> Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah ; **and those with him are forceful against the disbelievers, merciful among themselves. You see them bowing and prostrating [in prayer], seeking bounty from Allah and [His] pleasure. Their mark is on their faces from the trace of prostration**. That is **their description in the Torah**. And their **description in the Gospel is as a plant which produces its offshoots and strengthens them so they grow firm and stand upon their stalks, delighting the sowers** - so that Allah may enrage by them the disbelievers. Allah has promised those who believe and do righteous deeds among them forgiveness and a great reward.

so the Qur'an delivers two descriptions of the Sahaba () (I'm not sure how to understand this verse: whether the description should be of both our Prophet () and his companions or only his companions so let's assume that at least the common part applies) which should be in the books of the Ahl al-Kitab.

- Is it possible to give a clear reference to these description  -in the referenced sources (Torah and Gospel)?
- Or have they been changed?
- Or shouldn't we take the verse too literally?

Comment: [The Parable of the Mustard Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Mustard_Seed) and [The Parable of the Growing Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Growing_Seed) is relevant.